# google.script.run not getting invoked inside UI html backed by angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

For some reason `google.script.run.generator()` is not getting invoked. `$scope.formIsValid()` evaluates to true when form is valid and if I was to enter any other piece of code inside of that if statement it gets executed. `$scope.workout` is defined object and I didnt have problem accessing it in other parts of my code.

If I invoke google.script.run.generator inside of this submitWorkout function on its own as one statement it gets executed. When I run same example inside of browser as a standalone html file with this script it invokes google.script.run but throws exception as undefined which is understandable because its doesnt have it defined in its own scope. However when I run it inside of Google sheets html side bar and in appscript context it doesnt even enter if true block of the code. I am very confused please help.

```
 $scope.submitWorkout = function() {
      if($scope.formIsValid()) {
         google.script.run.generator($scope.workout);
         $scope.errorMessage = false;
      }else{
         $scope.errorMessage = true;
      }  
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I'm wondering whether you resolved your problem or if you're still looking for assistance.